# Excel - Create a pivot table by week that displays the weeks without dates with a null or 0 value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

to keep it simple I have a spreadsheet that has dates that I need to create a pivot table with, grouped by week. The challenge is that I need to see the weeks that do not have dates. In the end I want to have a chart so there may be a way just through the chart.

```
Example Data:
1/3/2017  - 137
1/18/2017 - 10
1/19/2017 - 20
1/30/2017 - 45
1/31/2017 - 15
```

I would need something that showed the week. I will use the week number and sum the second column for the example above example.

```
Week   - Data Total
1      -  137
2      -  0
3      - 30
4      -  0
5      - 60
```

I am not picky whether it is using MDX a formula, group, chart etc. The only thing that I do not want to do is add a date from all the missing weeks into the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the Pivot Table using those two columns (dates as rows and numbers as values), then rightclick on the rows and select Group -> Days -> Number of Days 7, it'll divide all your dates into weeks and sum the values of each day. Want the weeknumbers? Add a column to the left of your Pivot Table and enter this formula:

```
=WEEKNUM(LEFT(B64;FIND(" ";B64 ) - 1 );2)
```

Substitute B64 for the cell of the Pivot Table containing the week range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try:

[image]

The formula based on my setup:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM($A$2:$A$6+0,2)=E2),$B$2:$B$6)`

Try and let me know if this works or not.